# GitHub Actions source file

Tags: kubernetes, github-actions, cicd

how do I source this file which is in another repo. here is the GitHub action workflow example which is used in another project. I used the same code, its complaining that "file is not found"

```html
run: |
        # Setting up cluster configurations, config files are in the kubectl image
        # https://github.com /kube-apps/tree/master/kubectl
        source /gke/gke-clusters.config
        source /aks/aks-clusters.config
```

Comment: better try to put theses in files in secrets and avoid to store them in a git repo, not looking good for security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the full path to the source lines.

```
run: |
# Setting up cluster configurations, config files are in the kubectl image
# https://github.com/kube-apps/tree/master/kubectl
source https://github.com/ /kube-apps/tree/master/kubectl/gke-clusters.config
source https://github.com /kube-apps/tree/master/kubectl/aks-clusters.config
```

Comment: Thank you. what path/location does the "source" command reads from. I would like to create new files in current repo and have it sourced